# Vertically stretch div

Tags: css

I have 3 div elements

`< div id="header">FIXED CONTENT< /div >

< div id="content">DYNAMIC CONTENT< /div >

< div id="footer">FIXED CONTENT< /div >`

How can make it so, that the header stays at top, the footer at the bottom & the content div to stretch vertically & fill the gap between header & footer.
I hope the question is clear.

Comment: you mean bottom of browser window or bottom of content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure CSS:

```
#header {
  height: 100px;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this witout setting a fixed height for the header & footer?

Comment: The only way would be to be able to specify `#content { height: (100% - #footer.height - #header.height; }`. There might be some crazy future CSS3 stuff but nothing cross-browser right now. In my life, usually the header and footer can have a fixed height.

Comment: Yeah, or JS. You don't want to have the foundation of your layout dependent on that though!

Comment: these types of lay-outs are most often used in very rich web apps (e.g. MockingBird, GitHub Issues, Google Maps, although without a footer) so maybe JavaScript is not a big problem.