# Variable sized banner and content under it with scroll

Tags: html, css

this is what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/txvxJ/

```
<div style="position: fixed; overflow: scroll; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0px; background: red;">a<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1</div>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: height: auto; background-color: yellowgreen;"><img src="http://prog.hu/site/images/logo.gif" width="100%" /></div>
```

the only problem is, the red content goes under the banner, thats wrong. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a little bit of javascript you can do it like this

```
window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('bannerImg'),
    cs = (window.getComputedStyle) ? window.getComputedStyle(img, '') : img.currentStyle;

    document.getElementById('content').style.top = cs.height;
}

<div id="content" style="position: absolute; overflow: scroll; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0px; background: red;">a<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1<br />1</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: auto; background-color: yellowgreen;"><img id="bannerImg" src="http://prog.hu/site/images/logo.gif" width="100%" /></div>
```

But if you resize the window, the layout would get screwed up. You would solve it simply by setting this function to window.onresize event.

Comment: Using javascript is probably the only way to set the position or margin, read comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912539/vertically-stretch-div Or maybe using some new CSS3 also... ???